# django website with gunicorn errror using chrome when login user

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, gunicorn

i have a strange error with my website which created by django .

for the server i use gunicorn and nginx .yes it works well at first,when i use firefox to test my website.

i create an account ,login the user ,once i submit the data,the user get login .

one day i change to chrome to test my website ,i go to the login page,fill in the user name and password,click the submit button ,this user get login ,when i refresh the page,the strange thing is ,the website ask me to login again ,it means the user do not login at that time.this happens only in chrome .i test in IE and firefox ,all works well.

my english is not good,i description the error again.

when i use chrome ,i login one account,the page show the account get login already,however i refresh the page or i click to other page,the website show the user is not in login status.
this error only in chrome.

and if i stop guncorn ,i start the website use django command .manage.py runserver.
even i user chrome ,the error do not appear.

i do not know what exact cause the problem.

any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The session information, i.e. which user is logged in, is saved in a cookie, which is send from browser to server with each request. The cookie is set through the server with your login request.
For some reason, chrome does not send or save the correct cookie. If you have a current version of each browser, they should behave similar. Older browser versions may not be as strict as newer versions in respect to cookie security:

1. Same origin: are all pages located at the same sub-domain, or is the login page at some other domain?
2. path: do you set the cookie for a specific path, but use URLs with other paths?
3. http-only: Do you try to set or get a cookie with javascript, which is set `http-only`?
4. secure-only: Do you use https for the login-page but http for other pages?

Look at the developer tools in chrome Resources -> Cookies which cookies are set and if they change with each login. Delete all cookies, and try again.